# [Unity3D]How to make a random terrain with random forest and random grass

Tags: unity-game-engine, random, terrain

I want make a war game with random map. I already generate map with random height, but I don't know how to generate random location tree and grass by Unity terrain's place tree and paint detail tool.

Can terrain paint detail with random location?

Comment: Unfortunately, Unity doesn't support it as a built-in functionality. But some users did scripts for that. Look at here, it should be a good starting point: https://forum.unity.com/threads/mass-place-grass.42216/ there's a script for painting a terrain in a massive way, you could integrate the random logic.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but not out-of-the-box. You'll have to create a script for it.. I can't give you the full code to something like that because it was be gigantic, but you want to start looking into Raycasts.